# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Common.Province>'l C# MVc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My Code is here below

```
List<Province> ldb = (from k in db.Provinces
                      join c in db.Countrys on k.CountryID equals c.CountryID
                      select new { k.ProvinceID, k.ProvinceName, c.CountryName }).ToList();
ViewBag.Province = ldb;
```

I want display simple in table and join with country to display country name in table. The error is following

> Error  6   Cannot implicitly convert type
>      'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to
>      'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Common.Province>'

```
public class Province
{
    [Key]
    public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Country> CountryCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your province class? I don't think its being mapped to a correct type! Use var and see what is expected output type suggested on hover.

Comment: @touchofevil public class Province
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
        public string Description  { get; set; }
    

        [NotMapped]
        public List<Country> CountryCollection { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You need to create a view model containing the properties from `Province` and `Country` that you want, and then use `select new YourViewModel { ... }`

Comment: @UmerZaman - Please don't put classes in comments - you should edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its clear from the error that you cannot convert `anonymous` type to `generic` type and its not proper way to use domain models into view so you should create another class which is called `ViewModel` this class is used for specific view in your case you need both `country name` and `province`  so your `ViewModel` will be

```
public class ProvinceCountryViewModel
    {
         public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
         public string ProvinceName { get; set; }
         public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

and your `linq` will be

```
List<ProvinceCountryViewModel> ldb = (from k in db.Provinces
                      join c in db.Countrys on k.CountryID equals c.CountryID
                      select new  ProvinceCountryViewModel{ProvinceID = k.ProvinceID, ProvinceName=k.ProvinceName,CountryName = c.CountryName }).ToList();
ViewBag.Province = ldb;
```

and in `view`

```
 @foreach (var value in  (List<ProvinceCountryViewModel>) ViewBag.Province )
    {

      // here you can access properties like value.CountryName 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `select` in `LINQ`, you need to create new Province class instance, not anonymous object.

```
select new Province{ /*assign properties here*/ }).ToList();
```

Comment: That will throw an error. And the `Province` model does not contain a property named `CountryName`

Comment: here i can select only Province item but also want to select country

Comment: See OP's comment on the answer by Marcus H

Answer (score 0):

Return the province type as mentioned below

```
 List<Province> ldb = (from k in db.Provinces
  join c in db.Countrys on k.CountryID equals c.CountryID
  select new Province { k.ProvinceID, k.ProvinceName, c.CountryName }).ToList();
     ViewBag.Province = ldb;
```